# C++: Creating Polygons from images' transparency

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, polygon

Alright guys..
I'm at a loss here. I've been trying to code an image to polygon converter to no avail, it's really bugging me. It's supposed to create a polygon from the transparency of an image (the non transparent part is the polygon). I've seen programs that do it, but they were closed-source and really expensive. It's not just edge-detection, it's polygon generalization and hole-detection as well, all this in a Box2D compatible, triangulated polygon.
Please hand me some tips on this, or a library name, or an algorithm or something..
Thanks!

Comment: Is the image a polygon, like a square or triangle, or is it more complex like a tiger's face?

Comment: It's a complex image, the user can input anything.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at the openCV library. It has several useful algorithms and tools for
image processing. I think you can accomplish your goal with it.
Good luck.

Comment: I can't quite seem to find the required function/class in OpenCV, mind pointing to the one you were thinking of?